# Docker PHP application start

Tags: php, docker

I'm trying to run a ready PHP app (a copy of existing site - just want to run it locally) in Docker.

I tried some from that: https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/dockerizing-a-php-application but no luck. One friend told me that I should also have a server for that which confused me a bit. I know PHP have self-hosting capabilities (not recommended for production tho, but I need it just for testing purposes).

I also tried `docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script -p 8080:8080 -v /Users/jans/Developer/sfolder:/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp php:5.6 bash` and run it from bash with `php index.php` (and yes - I used `ls` earlier to see if there are any files in there and they are), but nothing happens and `localhost:8080` is not available.

I'm also trying to use https://hub.docker.com/r/1and1internet/ubuntu-16-nginx-php-phpmyadmin-mysql-5/ but this is really complicated to me and can't do anything at all with it.

Anyone with experience how to run PHP app will be more than welcome.

Comment: Is `index.php` launching a web server…? Probably not, it's just executing your `index.php` once without much of an effect most likely. You need to run a web server which hosts your PHP files. PHP's built-in dev server can do, or a proper server like Apache or nginx. But just `php index.php` won't do that.

Comment: How do I find it? It's a legacy app - and there's a lot of files tbh...

Comment: Have you tried to run `php -S localhost:8080` from your application's root folder to use PHP's own server. It's as simple as that for very basic applications. If you need a database, docker is a good way to create an environment that suits your needs but it has a steep learning curve. Maybe use a (L/W/M)AMP stack?

Comment: It looks like it's running in console, but browser still shows nothing. And yes, app is using MySql database, but I should be able at least to start page even if db is not connected yet (I suppose so at least)

Comment: Is apache or some webserver running too in your php container? Try maybe: the php image with tag: 5.6-apache